# ListView in a HorizontalScrollView in Android

Tags: android, listview, horizontalscrollview

I have an `ListView` inside a `HorizontalScrollView` and it works perfectly fine, except for the initial load.  I'm loading the data for the list view from a web service so I created a thread to do that.  Once I have the data, I simply call `_myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and the data becomes visible in the `ListView`.  But if the `ListView` is far off the screen, the containing `HorizontalScrollView` will automatically scroll to make this `ListView` visible.  How can I call `notifyDataSetChanged` without making the `ListView` scroll into the current view?

Here's an idea of how I have my layout XML file:

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/my_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/my_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ListView android:id="@+id/my_list"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: not working for me... list is shown vertically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try making your ListView invisible until after you've called `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/my_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Then in the code:

```
_myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);
listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Not sure if this will work...  worth a shot, though.

Comment: Yeah.  I did this, but I didn't set to to "gone" initially, just "invisible".  It does solve the problem, but I don't know.  Seems like a workaround.  Maybe I'll file a bug with the Android team - I can't find anything in the documentation which says I'm doing this wrong.

Thanks for your answer.